# mapview is not showing before it load all data

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

i have one application it has mapview .

problem is that i want to show map. means right now when all data loaded then it show mapview. i want to show mapview before it loaded . how can i do this ?

Edit:

for show map i use this `[self performSelector:@selector(methoname) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.02];`

but by this other problem generate .problem is ,it show me two times activity indicator. any other thing ,like performselector but without activity indicator.

[image]

i dont want to show this thing.

Comment: Could you provide more information - have you added the mapview programmatically or with the IB? Could you post the code where you add data to the mapview?

Comment: my problem is different ...i wnat to show map image or u can say mapview before all data show in this.i have added mapview in xib.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. If you have added the mapview with IB, it should be there as soon as the view is loaded, unless you have marked it as "hidden". You can zoom in to any place you want using setRegion:animated. Even without loading any data the mapview should be visible.

Comment: Phillipp, I think he's downloading tertiary data along with the map's normal data. This is what's getting him. Refer to my answer.

Comment: It seems like the downloading of map data by the mapview interfers with the downloading of your map data. Try Aurum Aquila's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at multithreading.

Basically, you should be retrieving your data in a background thread. If you do what you're doing right now (loading everything in the main thread) the UI cannot be updated until everything is loaded.

So, do something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    mapView.hidden = NO;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getExtraMapData)];
}

-(void)getExtraMapData{
    NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self downloadMapData];
    [map addTheDataIDownloaded];//I've never used the mapView, 
                                // so I don't know it's methods.
    [pool release];
}

-(void)downloadMapData{
    NSURL *mapDataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://aURLWithInfoForMyMap.com"];
    NSData *mapData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapDataURL];
}
```

Comment: Uh, what's wrong with having a static picture of the map and then hiding it when the map finishes loading?